# PostgreSQL function does not work properly

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a simple PostgreSQL function..something like below

```
CREATE FUNCTION reffunc(refcursor) RETURNS refcursor AS '
BEGIN
    OPEN $1 FOR 

    SELECT col 
    FROM   test
    WHERE  cola = 1;

    RETURN $1;
END;
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

the thing is when I run the following sql, say I get 10 rows

```
    SELECT col 
    FROM   test
    WHERE  cola = 1;
```

but when i call the function i get 0 rows back, later after varying the script i found that the following works

```
CREATE FUNCTION reffunc(refcursor) RETURNS refcursor AS '
BEGIN
    OPEN $1 FOR 

    SELECT col 
    FROM   test     t
    WHERE  t.cola = 1;

    RETURN $1;
END;
' LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

and returns the necessary rows.

I know this is not strictly a SQL issue, but is this a well known PostgreSQL issue or possibly a bug?

A point of note here is that I have a number of tables with columns named 'cola', is that the reason or is there a PostgreSQL config issue?

32bit Windows version of PostgreSQL v8.3

Answer (score 1):

Your question is rather vague, so I'm guessing in the dark here. Could you by any chance, already have a variable called "cola" in your function? When function-level variables conflict column names, the variable takes precedence and you end up with totally unexpected results to your query.

The solution is to rename the variable in your function.

This is a very common pitfall in PL/pgSQL. PostgreSQL 9.0 and newer detect such conflicts.